# Devise - Changing the name of a routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

By default Devise creates a routing for a sign-in as '/sign_in'.

How would I change the path so that it is '/log_in'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding scope

```
devise_for :users
   devise_scope :user do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in the end, given that I was already inserting controllers to handle aspects of Devise:

in routes.rb

```
#Add Devise authentication to users, handling omniauth callbacks in users/omniauth_callbacks_controller
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions],
                   :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks',
                                       :registrations => 'users/registrations'
                                      }

# :skip => [:sessions] tells devise not to create routes for sessions, allowing us to declare our own
as :user do
  get 'users/log_in' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post 'users/log_in' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  delete 'users/log_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```